# AppDelegate to UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a sample code with a header and an implementation file and the two appDelegate files. I would like to add what the project does to my app. The first two files are a ViewController file, so I just need to drag it in, but the other two are `AppDelegate`, and I obviously can't have two app delegates. But in the case of this sample app the app delegate is used as a proper viewcontroller, because in the .m file of the `UIViewController` file, there is this code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Since the `AppDelegate` doesn't implement methods such as applicationWillBecomeActive:, how can I transform the file into a UIViewController file? What do I need to change in the code above to call the controller, instead of the Delegate (my AppDelegate will so remain untouched).

The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.1-howtos/tree/master/SendRequestsHowTo)

This is what I have done (the code needs the Facebook API to be included). Go on the download tab and download Archive.zip and AppDelegate.zip: https://github.com/Alexmitico45/FacebookRequests/downloads

Basically the controller `ContactFBSViewController` is linked the a viewcontroller in the storyboard.

Comment: Any chance we could see the sample code?  It's hard to deduce exactly what your issue is, without seeing the code.

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE, (THE CODE NEEDS THE FACEBOOK API TO BE IMPORTED): https://github.com/Alexmitico45/FacebookRequests/downloads ...go on downloads and download the archive.zip (4 files). Basically the controller ContactFBSViewController is linked the a viewcontroller in the storyboard.

Comment: NOTE: I have followed the code and you can you download the files I have created the website provided above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. What I had to do is make the viewcontroller a singleton:

```
+ (FacebookViewController *) sharedManager;
```

..then use this code to access it:

```
FacebookManager *manager = [FacebookManager sharedManager];
```

And after days of trial and error it finally works!!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want the functionality of the `AppDelegate` in the sample to be in your app.  But you don't want to replace your app's existing AppDelegate?

An AppDelegate class isn't really any different from another class.  What differentiates it is the fact that it implements `UIApplicationDelegate`, and is explicitly referred to in `main.m`, as the startup class for your app.

If you want to transform that into just another class, I would:

1. Rename the class (.h, .m, interface and implementation names), then put it in your project.
2. In NewName.h, remove the implementation of UIApplicationDelegate at the top.
3. In NewName.m, you want to look at any of the functionality in the **UIApplication methods** section, as that's functionality specifically allocated to be performed by an AppDelegate class, and see if or how that needs to be merged into your existing AppDelegate class.  Then remove those UIApplicationDelegate methods from NewName.m, as they can only exist there when you implement UIApplicationDelegate.

Since `ViewController` takes advantage of the fact that its expected AppDelegate is a long-lived class in the UIApplication hierarchy, you'll need to replicate that behavior.  This is probably most easily achieved by creating a new weak property to reference `NewName`, in ViewController.h:

**ViewController.h**

```
@class NewName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NewName *newNameDelegate;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "NewName.h"

...

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize newNameDelegate;

...

- (IBAction)sendRequestButtonAction:(id)sender {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [newNameDelegate sendRequest];
    }
}
```

**NewName.m**

```
...

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.viewController.newNameDelegate = self;

...
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea of where to start.

Comment: great answer, I will try this out and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that I need to add the self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.viewController.newNameDelegate = self; in the NewName.m ?? Because in the actual project its the viewcontroller.h that has the button properties

Comment: I don't think that the NewName is called, because I placed an alert in the view did load and it doesn't show, but I can see that the functions are imported because if I remove the #import it gives errors

Comment: I didn't add explicit code in the example to show it, but you would need to add code to your existing AppDelegate (for example in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) to allocate and call an instance of NewName.  I'm unclear as to the extent to which you don't want to edit your existing AppDelegate class.  You'll have to edit it to some degree, since it's the entry point from which all functionality gets initiated in your app.  Ideally, you'd just merge the relevant parts of the example AppDelegate into your own, and ViewController could remain more or less untouched.

Comment: I did that, but still when I press the button auth that is declared in the Viewcontroller, nothing happens. I gave altrady added the lther features to my app delegate

Comment: It's this part that is unclear: ...

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.viewController.newNameDelegate = self;

...
And the line. Provided in the question.mi beleive tha it needs to be replaced to alloc the newName...

Comment: I am getting: Error: HTTP status code: 400 when I press the log in

Comment: I think that this is the reason: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
             openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
          annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    self.openedURL = url;
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}         ...I thinks its not being called