# Call open Url in appDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this code in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
     openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
  annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url
self.openedURL = url;
// attempt to extract a token from the url
 return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];       
 }
```

how can I call it from a UIViewController??

EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)authButtonAction:(id)sender {


/*
 AppDelegate *appDelegate =
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];*/

 // The user has initiated a login, so call the openSession method
 // and show the login UX if necessary.
 //[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];

 // If the user is authenticated, log out when the button is clicked.
 // If the user is not authenticated, log in when the button is clicked.
 if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
 [FacebookDialogueViewControllerDelegate closeSession];
 } else {
 // The user has initiated a login, so call the openSession method
 // and show the login UX if necessary.
 [FacebookDialogueViewControllerDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
 }


}
```

...the view controller then has this:

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Pass the `NSURL` into the `UIViewController` on instantiation or otherwise.
2. From your `UIViewController`, get a reference to the app delegate and the use the `openedURL` property.

**Code for Option 2**

```
MyViewController *controller = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
controller.openedURL;
```

Comment: originally the delegate was called like this: AppDelegate *appDelegate =
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; ...if i use option 2, do I need to add that code in the delegate or in the view controller?

Comment: but when is the open url actually called?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  This gets called by the OS when you register the URL syntax in the plist of your app.

You can then use this method to deal with the request.

i.e. if you have a wordsearch app then you may have it so that a user can open a wordsearch from a link in an email like...

wordsearch://thisisthecontetnofthewordsearchhfsadkljfhasdkfjahsdkfjhaskljasdhflkjahsgdflkjadhslfkj

Then you would use this function to parse the string and turn it into an actual wordsearch puzzle (or something like this).

What is it you are actually wanting to do from your UIViewController?

Comment: when I press a button, I am trying to instantiate a login with Facebook, and I need an url. The code above provides the url, and is in the app delegate, but I am not able to call that method form the UIViewcontorller

Comment: Ah, which version of Facebook API are you using?  Could you post some of the code you are trying to run.  For Facebook you don't have to run this code.  You should be setting a Facebook Delegate.  When the login returns it will run a specific method in the Facebook delegate.

Comment: It looks like you're running quite an old version of the Facebook API?   I'd recommend using the CocoaPods Facebook API here... http://cocoapods.org/?q=name%3Afacebook Also, what are you using Facebook for?  Are you just posting to Facebook or are you wanting to do more?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334989/appdelegate-to-uiviewcontroller ...this is what I was trying to do. Send a request